# Pointer arithmetic when void has unknown size

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic

In Visual Studio C++ version 9 (and probably other versions too), the following code:

```
int a = sizeof(void);
void const *b = static_cast<void const *>("hello world");
b += 6;
```

Generates [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9adz64y0.aspx) [errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kay26wa%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
error C2070: 'void': illegal sizeof operand
error C2036: 'const void *' : unknown size
```

This code works under GCC, which treats [`sizeof(void)` as `1`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html#Pointer-Arith).

Is there some way around this limitation, as casting explicitly to `char *` for purposes of pointer arithmetic adds to the confusion (`void *` is well recognised and used as a typeless pointer to raw memory).

### Update0

- Please note, I'm well aware of the
  existence of the standard.
- I **want** to do raw pointer
  arithmetic.
- I take `sizeof(void)` to
  show that I'm well aware the fact
  that it isn't `1` is the
  cause of the problem.
- The code
  example is simply to demonstrate what
  is required to generate the errors.
- I know this isn't a "normal" way to use `void`, but this is C, and these things happen.
- Yes, people need to do this at low-level. I'm not after why, I'm after how. If you want to know why, take a look at some kernel source, or your friendly glibc.

### Update1

It seems this question has generated a great deal of confusion. The question is not about *why* having `sizeof(void) == 1` is not standard, but what to do when it isn't.

In the instance that single-byte pointer arithmetic is to be done, it turns out that casting to `char *` is the correct answer, not because `*(void *)` has no size, but because the standard actually guarantees that `*(char *)` is always `1`. Therefore the use of `char *` is always correct, and congruent with `void *` with the GCC extension for the purposes of raw pointer arithmetic.

To further reinforce the point, `void *` is the correct choice for pointers to typeless memory, and `char *` is the correct type to cast to **for raw pointer arithmetic**.

Comment: It's not a limitation. You shouldn't be doing anything with a `void *` pointer other than casting it to another pointer type.

Comment: What is void? It is nothing, and has no size. GCC has that with something to do with C, IIRC.

Comment: Why would you ever need to write code that needs to know the size of void???

Comment: `void *` maybe very used as a pointer to typeless data, but `void` is never used as a datatype. What is `a`'s role in the code? You end up only using `b` in the other lines of code.

Comment: Strictly, the MSVC compiler is right and GCC is wrong - sizeof(void) is a nonsense expression that should be a compilation error.  According to the C standard, it is (_emphatically_) not 1.

Comment: Please read the question and the links carefully before commenting, some of these comments aren't very well thought out.

Comment: Don't come to us asking a question, then state your understanding of the situation is greater than ours. Doing any arithmetic with a raw void is meaningless, and any practice with it is bad practice.

Comment: Kernel source/glibc is practically written in assembler. You can do whatever you want to at that level because you know what you're doing. In C, it's assumed you _want_ a little bit of type-safety. If you want to use a `void *` pointer, you cast it to something else first. End of story.

Comment: "Yes, people need to do this at low-level". No, they don't *need* to do it. GCC provides it as a convenience, to save the programmer some typing. You could `#define advance(ARG1, ARG2) ((ARG1) = (void*)((ARG2) + (char*)(ARG1)))`, then `advance(b,6);`. You'd probably want a `plus` macro as well, to replace `b + 6`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: "Kernel source/glibc is practically written in assembler". No, kernel source is almost overwhelmingly C. That's how kernels manage to be portable between architectures. The bare minimum is written in assembler.

Comment: I don't think many people "need" to do something which is, by definition, impossible.

Comment: There is no good reason not to use a pointer to (unsigned) char for this purpose. It's what the NT kernel devs do, for example (no stupid gcc extensions for the NT kernel, after all). If you think it's ugly, create a macro or something.

Comment: As I've pointed out in my answer below, an appropriate answer now I have more information is that `char *` _is_ the correct pointer type to use for this. Not just because we all want to lark about how void is typeless blah blah.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It would appear the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864956/byte-precision-pointer-arithmetic-in-c-when-sizeofchar-1) is to use `char *` for pointer arithmetic, because `sizeof(char)` is always defined to be 1, and to be of the finest addressable granularity on any platform.

So in short, there is no way around the limitation, `char *` is in fact the proper way to do it.

[Matthias Wandel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20073/matthias-wandel) had the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864352/void-has-unknown-size-in-visual-c/1864369#1864369) but with a different justification.

Comment: Your question was not about what would be the correct type for pointer arithmetic. Your question was about why MSVC spat an error for `sizeof( void )` and if there is "any way around this limitation" (which there is not, as Matthias and others pointed out correctly). Including some strong words towards people trying to be helpful. Be a man and accept another's answer instead of complaining how the correct answer didn't fit your broken question...

Comment: ...and a week later, there's your "accepted" answer rated -2, while the answer you claim has not the correct "justification" is rated 11...

Comment: i'm not changing it. i know what i meant, and i knew the answer when i saw it. "is there a way around this limitation?": "no, and here's why". if someone makes a more accurate answer, i'll be happy to change. Matthias' answer is quite correct, but not what i was after.

Answer (score 18):

Incrementing a pointer is technically supposed to increment it by whatever size of thing that its pointing at.  Void points at nothing, so the size is unknown.

Its a nicety for some compilers to let you increment void pointers.

Casting is annoying, because you have to either cast it to another pointer, and then back, or do something awkward like `(*(char *)&voidptr) += 6`

Personally, I'd just declare it as a `char *` for purposes of arithmetic

Comment: Maybe you wanted `(*(char **)&voidptr) += 6`?  I don't believe the code snippet currently there does quite what you imply it does.

Comment: Managu is right. Yet, this would be an act or raw *reinterpretation* of `void *` pointer as a `char *` pointer. Reinterpretation is always a bad idea. Better use a *conversion* as in `voidptr = (char *) voidptr + 6`.

Comment: I've been implementing a linked list using void pointers. When the list is created it is passed a `size_t data_size` so it can perform copying operations etc. Now I've come to the problem of creating a list-to-array conversion routine. The intuitive (for me) thing to do was to add `data_size` to the void pointer to move it to the next item in the array... Never mind. I've upvoted this question because it has proven useful.

Answer (score 10):

In C language `sizeof` cannot be applied to incomplete types. `void` is an incomplete type, which is why you can't use it as operand of `sizeof`.

Pointer arithmetic of `void *` pointers is also not supported in C. In order to be used with pointer arithmetic the pointer has to point to object type, which `void` is not.

GCC allows both as a weird language extension.

Comment: Strangely enough it is not considered an error in _paranoid mode_ unless either `-Werror` or `-pedantic-errors` is specified. I just came across exactly the same conclusion when I took a look at the Standard.

Answer (score 6):

`void *` is meant to imply "pointer to unknown"

Adding 6 to a void pointer is therefore undefined, because you're asking the compiler to advance the pointer by "the size of 6 unknown objects".

You should not be doing it.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different questions here.  The first is for `void`, and the second for `void*`.  They are different types, and have little in common beside the name.

`void` is used mainly for function declarations/definitions (as the return type or to mean "takes no arguments").  You can't ever possibly have an object of type `void`.  Ever.  So it's hard to see a need to find out the size of that nonexistent object.  [GCC's behavior is nonstandard, and an intentional extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html).  However, I believe they chose `sizeof(void) == 1` because the C++ standard requires every object to take at least one byte of space.

`void*` means "pointer to real data, but without the relevant type information."  It is entirely possible to have `void*`; and you will run into them, a lot.  However, because the type information is ignored you can't manipulate the pointer much.  This is by design, because if you don't know what you have you really don't know what you can do with it.

But if you want to treat the memory as a collection of bytes then `char*` does that.  A `char` is one byte, everywhere.  A string of bytes is a `char*`.  If you find this weird, use `byte*` (where you define `byte` as something like `unsigned char`).

Comment: No, GCC giving an answer of 1 is an implementation detail. `void` is an incomplete type, and as such it should not be possible to take the size of it. GCC is in error, here.

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer.  GCC's behavior is an intentional extension ( http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html ), and I believe they picked a size of 1 because the C++ standard requires any object to take up at least one byte.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the error on the first line at least - you have sizeof(void) and it should be sizeof(void*), no?

Comment: `sizeof void` is meaningless. Change your approach.

Answer (score 1):

For purely pointing at raw data and incrementing that pointer by the number of bytes a chunk of data occupies, I always use `char *`. I then recast the pointer to a relevant data structure pointer once I need to treat it as something specific. Incrementing a `void *` isn't portable among compilers.

Comment: Incrementing a `void *` is of course a terrible idea... but so is acting like your solution is better. Like most other `reinterpret_cast`s, casting from `char *` to an incompatible type of pointer and dereferencing the result isn't defined, violates aliasing rules, and subverts platform alignment requirements. So, unless all of your data structures are compatible through having only a single `char` member each, which is unlikely... the only "portable" thing about this advice is its role as a pure UB generator.

Comment: I posted this >6.5 years ago and assumed that one would use it if only they knew what they were doing for their platform. :) Having said that, on platforms that often require low-level programming to eke out full performance (think console games, where I spent the majority of my past 20 years), this is still common despite middleware like Unity making a decent penetration. (And, for the record, this method is often used *exactly* for the reason of having to deal with platform alignment requirements.) But, no worries, I only got one upvote so far in almost 7 years, so you're safe. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> void * is well recognised and used as a typeless pointer to raw memory.

Correct. Not having a type means not having a size either.

Comment: now what about the actual question?

Comment: What about it? You apparently finally accepted that sizeof( void ) is nonsense because void does not have a size, about the same time you posted the above comment.