# Custom Memory Manager

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a custom memory manager and I am wondering if there is a better way to implement this function, as when I am  asked about void pointer arithmetic, several people thought that if I had a void* in C++, something was very wrong.

```
// allocates a page of memory.
void ObjectAllocator::allocatePage()
{    
    //if(OAStats_.PagesInUse_ >= Config_.MaxPages_)
        //throw exception

    void* buffer = ::operator new(OAStats_.PageSize_); // allocate memory, no constructor call.

    // =============== Setup the PageList_ ===============
    GenericObject* pNewNode = ::new(buffer) GenericObject();    // Construct GenericObject for the pagelist.
    pNewNode->Next = PageList_->Next;                            // pNewNode points to wherever PageList_ pointed to.
    PageList_->Next = pNewNode;                                    // PageList_ points to pNewNode
    pNewNode = NULL;                                            // dont need this handle anymore
    buffer = static_cast<char*>(buffer) + sizeof(GenericObject);    // move pointer to point after the generic object.

    // =============== Setup the FreeList_ ===============
    for(int i=0;i<Config_.ObjectsPerPage_;++i)
    {
        static GenericObject* pPreviousNode = NULL;            // static variable to hold the previous node
        pNewNode = ::new(buffer) GenericObject();            // Construct GenericObject for the freelist.
        pNewNode->Next = pPreviousNode;
        pPreviousNode = pNewNode;
        buffer = static_cast<char*>(buffer) + OAStats_.ObjectSize_;    // move pointer by ObjectSize.
        ++OAStats_.FreeObjects_;
    }
    FreeList_->Next = pNewNode;

    ++OAStats_.PagesInUse_;
    ++OAStats_.Allocations_;
}
```

Comment: "several people thought that if i had a void* in C++, something was very wrong." <-- I would not agree with that. Void pointers have their uses. I suppose it comes down to whether you are part of the 'anti-C' C++ community, or not. I tend to say that while yes, C++ is  a higher level language than C, people often do low-level things in it and so there is nothing wrong with using its more 'C-like' features.

Comment: @Stephen: Why is it that so many programmers have this knee-jerk reflex that when a concept is criticized they just *have* to say "it's not evil, it has its uses". I suppose you say the same about singletons and gotos. But in this case, what are the uses of a void*? Why should he use a void* here?

Comment: @Jalf Because negative comments stick in people's minds far more than positive comments. That means that if someone who is new to programming, or has not heard of X before, reads a comment that slates X and says you should never use it, they are likely to take that knowledge and equate it as a fact in their mind. Moreso, I was merely stating an opinion. Would you have replied similarly if I had backed up the "don't use void pointers" view? Here no, there was no reason to use it, but the OP simply said that people had told him not to use them in general when coding C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need a block of memory for for storing a string (8-bit ANSI), it makes sense to declare a pointer to that buffer as char and operate on it.

In your case, you need a block of memory that is a 'blob', it has no inherent type, so you correctly chose void* to represent that blob.

Now you need to increment that pointer by the size of some object. You cannot perform arithmetic on a void pointer for obvious reasons, so what do you do? Cast it. There is no shame in that.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, on raw bytes, use a char*, and don't think any less of yourself.  It's The Right Thing To Do (tm).  Especially if you wrap it in a higher level construct, like you have.

Comment: Slight nuance here. For API interfaces that accept pointers to arbitrary types as input, use `void*`. The reason being any `T*` will convert to `void*` without an explicit cast. This means users of the API won't have to cast pointers at all the call sites. Internally, you can `static_cast` to `char*` if you need to do arithmetic.

In **C++**, `T*` to `void*` is implicit, while `void*` to `T*` requires an explicit `static_cast`. **C** allows both directions without casting.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with the void*. However, what we often see is people coming from C who overuse void* when they should do something else. If you're managing raw memory blobs, then a void* is perfectly appropriate. However, there's rarely any other reason to do it.

Comment: +1. Out of interest, what are the typical ways in which to 'overuse void*' ?

Comment: void* data, int size; memcpy(data, buffer, size); instead of using template and copy constructor.