# void * arithmetic

Tags: c, auto-increment

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
   int i=10;
   void *k;
   k=&i;

   k++;
   printf("%p\n%p\n",&i,k);
   return 0;
}
```

Is ++ a legal operation on void* ? Some  books say that it's not 
but K & R doesn't say anything regarding void * arithmetic ( pg. 93,103,120,199 of K &R 2/e)

Please clarify.

PS : GCC doesn't complain at least in k++.

Comment: GCC doesn't complain at least !!

Comment: Take a look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864352/void-has-unknown-size-in-visual-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864956/byte-precision-pointer-arithmetic-in-c-when-sizeofchar-1

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html).

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to void and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.

If you add the `-pedantic` flag it will produce the warning:

> `warning: wrong type argument to increment`

If you want to abide to the standard, cast the pointer to a `char*`:

```
k = 1 + (char*)k;
```

---

The standard specifies one cannot perform addition (`k+1`) on `void*`, because:

1. Pointer arithmetic is done by treating `k` as the pointer to the first element (#0) of an array of `void` (C99 §6.5.6/7), and `k+1` will return element #1 in this "array" (§6.5.6/8).
2. For this to make sense, we need to consider an array of `void`. The relevant info for `void` is (§6.2.5/19)

   > The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be completed.
3. However, the definition of array requires the element type cannot be incomplete (§6.2.5/20, footnote 36)

   > Since object types do not include incomplete types, **an array of incomplete type cannot be constructed.**

Hence `k+1` cannot be a valid expression.

Answer (score 5):

No, arithmetic on `void*` is not covered by the standard. Use `char*` for this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot increment a pointer to `void`. The compiler does not know what is the sizeof target structure.

Comment: In my case it does know , GCC knows -

Comment: $ make 
gcc -g -Wall -o test test.c
$ ./test
0xbfcaf3d8
0xbfcaf3d9

Comment: Seems gcc considers k is an integer when incrementing it… What is  `&i + 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard requires that all pointer arithmetic operators require the pointer to be to a complete object type. `void` is an incomplete type. GCC is doing the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic on void* is a GCC extension. When I compile your code with `clang -Wpointer-arith` the output is :

```
test.c:9:4: warning: use of GNU void* extension [-Wpointer-arith]
k++;
~^
```

The usual behavior of a pointer increment is to add the size of the pointee type to the pointer value. For instance :

```
int *p;
char *p2;
p++; /* adds sizeof(int) to p */
p2 += 2; /* adds 2 * sizeof(char) to p2 */
```

Since `void` has no size, you shouldn't be able to perform pointer arithmetic on `void*` pointers, but GNU C allows it.