# incrementing a void pointer

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [void * arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922958/void-arithmetic)

Hi guys I have a small question regarding pointer increment in C. First let say that I know that `ptr++`, where `ptr`is a pointer will increment as much as the `sizeof(*ptr)`. Also I know that when doing `*ptr`, the compiler knows it has to grab `sizeof(*ptr)` bytes from memory.

The second part helps me understand why the following does not even compile:

```
int main(){
 int a = 3;
 void* b = &a;
 printf("%d\n", *b);
 return 0;
}
```

Because the compiler does not know the size of a variable of type `void`. However, I'm a little bit confused about the following code:

```
int main(){
 int a = 3;
 void* b = &a;
 printf("%p\n", b);
 b++;
 printf("%p\n", b);
}
```

So, my two questions are:

1. How is the compiler able to know how much it should increment `b`?
2. Why does it increment only one byte (at least in my machine is one byte)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922958/void-arithmetic

Comment: What's with all the trailing whitespace on the `printf` line of the 1st snippet? Ugh!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) it doesn't, 2) that's undefined behaviour. `void` is an incomplete type, so it doesn't have a well-defined size, so you cannot do pointer arithmetic with its pointers.

Typically you will want `char` pointers for byte-wise memory fiddling.

If you **compile with all compiler warnings enabled**, you will spot such problematic code.

Comment: Well, you don't necessarily need _all_ the warnings, but you should definitely try a few of them on for size.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: In GCC, I'd recommend `-W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (hence "all"), which gives you a *very* good basis. The compiler offers some more esoteric and subjective warnings (like `-Weffc++` for C++ for checking conformity to Scott Meyers's C++ book!) which I'm happy to skip ;-) Basically any warning that lets you know about blatant misuse of the language should be enabled...

Comment: gcc provides arithmetic on void pointers as an extension though. It treats the size as 1 when doing arithmetic. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html

Comment: @KerrekSB - I use `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` and a few others as well, but one of those (I think it's `-Wall`) turns on a warning for `if(x = something)`, which I don't like (I think the double parenthesized version it recommends to silence the warning is ugly). I wish you could disable warnings as easily as you could enable them.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Really? I get: `warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` This is on GCC 4.6.2.

Comment: @KerrekSB - That's the warning I don't like. I just find the extra parentheses to be a bit too Lispy.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: Ah, I understand. In your case you want `-Wno-parentheses` then :-)