# using pointer aritmetic in void*

Tags: c, memory, malloc, mmap

My machine is ubuntu 20.04

I have a assignment that say
"Using the system calls (mmap and munmap) implement your own functions for dynamic memory allocation: mymalloc and myfree, which have the same functionality as malloc and free from the standard C library. Save the implementations in files mymalloc.h and mymalloc.c."

And then it says
"we must allocate at least the desired length + the size of the variable for storing
the length (size_t). We store the length as first element, then return the next element."

It is my code (size is parameter in type size_t)

```
size_t total_size = size + sizeof(size_t);

size_t allocation_overflow = total_size % page_size;

if(allocation_overflow > 0)
    total_size += page_size - allocation_overflow;

void *data = mmap(NULL ,total_size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_PRIVATE , 0 , 0);

  // size_ptr will point to stored size
  size_t *size_ptr =(size_t *)data;

  size_ptr[0] = total_size;


  // pointer to allocated memory
  void* allocated_mem_pointer = data + sizeof(size_t);
```

and it give warning "pointer type 'void*' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer arith]"

ı must store the length in first element because assignment says it but ı don't warnings ı want to write clean code . İS there a legal for it. I already read  [Pointer arithmetic when void has unknown size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864352/pointer-arithmetic-when-void-has-unknown-size)
but couldnt find any answer to solve it.

Comment: You could make `data` a pointer to `char` (`char*`). You are incrementing by a number returned from `sizeof` and `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so you're basically incrementing by a multiple of `sizeof(char)` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, you cannot do arithmetics with `void*` unless you are using GCC extensions or similar.

The simple solution is: Don't use `void*`.

In your code you already have

```c
  // size_ptr will point to stored size
  size_t *size_ptr =(size_t *)data;
  size_ptr[0] = total_size;
```

Now you want to calculate the address that comes after your counter header.

The element that comes after `arr[0]` is simply `arr[1]`.

Use this to get the address for caller:

```c
  // pointer to allocated memory
  void* allocated_mem_pointer = &size_ptr[1];
```

When you want to get back to that header in your `myfree` function you can do similar trick:

```c
void myfree(void*addr) {
   size_t *buff = (size_t*) addr;
   size_t header = buff[-1];
   // ... 
}
```

This is valid because `buff[-1]` points into the same memory oject that was initially allocated in your `myalloc` function.

Note:

If you were to create a function that is not only used for educational purposes, you would also need to handle proper alignment for the address you return to the caller.

Comment: Could you tell me what are these GCC extensions and thanks for answer

Comment: GCC allows doing caculations to `void*`. Just as if it was `char*`. As with all extensions, they are not portable and I would not recommend to use them unless you really need to. Which is obviously never the case for this extension.

Comment: I rather suspect that the correct solution in this case is to use some manner of struct pointer where the first item is a `size_t`. Possibly a flexible array member at the end: `typedef struct { size_t size; uint8_t data[]; } heapseg_t;` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pointers arithmetic (`ie add a number to pointer`) you need to type your pointer properly:

```
IntPointer32Bits + 1 => will give the address of the next adjacent 32 bits integer
IntPointer16Bits + 1 => will give the address of the next adjacent 16 bits integer
```

The resulting address of pointer arithmetic depends on the pointer type.

```
void* allocated_mem_pointer = data + sizeof(size_t);
```

In this case, `data` is a `void *`, so the pointer arithmetic is not clear for the compiler (need to calculate next `8 bits`, `next 16 bits` or `next 32 bits` ?). You shouldn't use `void *` but you should have a real type instead, I assume `uint8_t`.

```
size_t total_size = size + sizeof(size_t);

size_t allocation_overflow = total_size % page_size;

if(allocation_overflow > 0)
    total_size += page_size - allocation_overflow;

uint8_t *data = mmap(NULL ,total_size, PROT_EXEC | PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_PRIVATE , 0 , 0);

  // size_ptr will point to stored size
  size_t *size_ptr =(size_t *)data;

  size_ptr[0] = total_size;


  // pointer to allocated memory
  uint8_t *allocated_mem_pointer = data + sizeof(size_t);
```

In this case, your intent is very clear for the compiler: the `allocated_mem_pointer` is a memory area composed of `uint8_t`, the computed address is the base address of `data` with an offset of `size_t` bytes. (the operator `sizeof` returns the number of bytes aka `uint8_t`.)

Comment: but if I type cast my void pointer data can ı return that "data" pointer without any problem. Maybe not int first try but is there any problem in multiple calls

Comment: Yes you can also cast it before doing the arithmetic. `void* allocated_mem_pointer = (uint8_t *)data + sizeof(size_t);` Should also work.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `void*`, do arithmetic on `char*` or `unsigned char*` pointers.

```
void *allocated_mem_pointer = (char*)data + sizeof(size_t);
```

Comment: or `(size_t *)data + 1`

Comment: I think it would be good if you explained why